# Calculated Column Formula 1st Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

In SPO:
I'm looking to get the following achieved with two columns, "Current Date" and "Original Date". The original date is my calculated column.

I want Original Date to be populated with the Current date's first value (other than blank) but not change afterwards.

Is Power Automate my only solution? I don't seem to find a solution to this otherwise.

Comment: I think something is missing from your question. If you want to store the "current date" then your need is covered with the "created" field, no?

Comment: Sorry didn't realise there could be a confusion with my item names. "Current Date" is the current date for the project's estimated end. Not today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely.

For Power Automate,

1. Create an **Automated cloud flow**
2. Use **When an item is created** as the trigger
3. Add an **Update item** operation where *Original Date*  will be set with *Current Date* value

Sample screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I agree with thebernardlim.Per my knowedge,there is no other way to achieve the value will not change.

Comment: Sorry, my question might've a bit unclear.

The 'Current Date' and 'Original Date' are the project's estimated end date. Not the actual current date.
I'm using "When an item is created or modified" since this date often isn't determined when the item is created but this will take whatever date is in 'Current Date' anytime an item changes in that row.
Basically, 'Original Date' has to have the 1st date ever entered in 'Current Date'.

Comment: Basically, I want to do this: https://ibb.co/Y8530kn @thebernardlim

Comment: hey @Droppisalt, I wrote an article on how to retrieve previous values of a SharePoint item which is what you might need. For your case, you will need to modify the flow slightly, where instead of retrieving the previous version, you will retrieve version 1.  https://dev.to/thebernardlim/power-automate-get-previous-value-of-updated-sharepoint-list-item-1kcb